# How to create a URL in Yii using value of a variable

Tags: php, url, yii

I'm using this lines to create a URL for update button.

```
'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/testSettings/update", array("id"=>$data->Id,"approval"=>0))'
```

This works fine as I have hardcoded the value for approval. Now I have to change this 0 with value of another variable $approval. How can I do this.
i.e I have to give this

```
'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/testSettings/update", array("id"=>$data->Id,"approval"=>$approval))'
```

Below is the attched code of the form

```
<form action="index.php">         
<?php $approval = Yii::app()->request->getParam('approval',"0");?>    
<?php echo CHtml::radioButtonList('approval',$approval,array('0'=>'Greetings Approval','1'=>'Contact Approval'),array(
    'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'),
    'onclick' => 'this.form.submit()', 
    'separator'=>''));     ?>
<?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('r', 'testSettings/admin'); ?>     
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try that code?

Comment: @Jon Yes I did...it is not working It says 'Undefined variable'. But, when I print the value of $approval I get 0 or 1 as output

Comment: Then you have a variable scope error. In any case, we cannot help you unless you show the code that did not work -- whatever is relevant, not just one line.

Comment: @Jon I attached the code just check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 possible ways of doing this I would say:

1. You create a method in your model (the class of the "$data" object) called "isApproved()" that either returns true or false according to your logic. You could then say

   ```
   'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/testSettings/update", array("id"=>$data->Id,"approval"=isApproved()))'
   ```
2. If the $approval variable is set somewhere in your view (which is not considered to be a good practice) then you could also use a closure like

   ```
   'url'=> function($data) use ($approval) { return CController::createUrl("/testSettings/update", array("id"=>$data->Id,"approval"=>$approval) }
   ```

Comment: For the first answer I got the following error.do not have a method or closure named "isApproved".